# uploading a png/plot to s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, plot, plotly

I can't figure out how to write images to my s3 bucket.   I use matplotlib and

```
import pandas as pd 
import boto3
import ploty.express as px 


path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/monthly-car-sales.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(path)
data.rename(columns = {'Month':'ds', 'Sales':'y'}, inplace=True)
fig1 = data.plot()
#type(fig1)
###
fig2=px.line(data, x='ds', y='y')
type(fig2)
```

I tried to do `fig1.savefig('s3://my_bucket_name/fig1.png')` and I get

> 'no such file or directory s3://my_bucket...'

If i do something like `data.to_csv('s3://my_bucket_name/data.csv')` my file gets written just fine. I've tried a variety of things with plotly using

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(fig1, key='s3://my_bucket_name/fig1.png')
```

But I can't get this to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image to a memory buffer, and upload that memory buffer directly to S3:

```python
import io

# Save the output to a Bytes IO object
png_data = io.BytesIO()
fig1.savefig(png_data)
# Seek back to the start so boto3 uploads from the start of the data
bits.seek(0)

# Upload the data to S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket="example-bucket", Key="results.png", Body=png_data)
```

Comment: thank you, this helped, although I'm not sure what the bits.seek(0) is supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

When using boto3 to upload a file, the format is:

```
response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
```

- `file_name` is the local file
- `bucket` is the name of the Amazon S3 bucket (`my_bucket_name`)
- `object_name` is the key of the Amazon S3 object

Therefore, use:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(fig1_filename, 'my_bucket_name', 'fig1.png')
```

Or, you can use keywords:

```py
s3_client.upload_file(Filename=fig1_filename, Bucket='my_bucket_name', Key='fig1.png')
```

Note that the value for `Filename` needs to be the name of a file on the disk, so you will need to save the data to disk first and then provide the name of that file. (It is possible to directly provide the data, but it is more complex due to the need to convert to the right data types.)

See: [upload_file - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_file.html)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the many AWS Python Developer Tutorials in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). This document contains many step by step dev instructions and functioning code in Github that you can use to learn concepts like this.

For your use case, i recommend looking at this doc.

[Detect objects in images with Amazon Rekognition using the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_python_3_topic.html)

Among the concepts that you will learn are:

- Upload photos to an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket.
- Use Amazon Rekognition to analyze and label the photos.
- Use Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES) to send email reports of
  image analysis.